# iphone gyro function is not being called

Tags: objective-c, xcode

We are trying to use the gyro , i have read about it, and i have this code running :

```
-(void)acceleratedInX:(float)xx Y:(float)yy Z:(float)zz
{
    NSLog(@"%f",xx); //x value
    NSLog(@"%f",yy); //y value
    NSLog(@"%f",zz);
}
```

i know that xcode should update this function when i put it on my delegate.
i just want to print up the x,y,z values
BUT its not happening..i dont get the NSLog, so the function isnt being called.
any help would be great
thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the update interval.

Your header should look like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate>
```

At the top of your .m declare this constant:

```
#define kAccelUpdate 30.0
```

in your viewDidLoad:

```
UIAccelerometer *theAccel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
[theAccel setUpdateInterval:1.0/kAccelUpdate];
[theAccel setDelegate:self];
```

then your listening method:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    NSLog(@"%g", acceleration.x);
    NSLog(@"%g", acceleration.y);
    NSLog(@"%g", acceleration.z ;
}
```

Also eventually you will have to put smoothing code in otherwise the accel is really jittery.

Comment: I HAVE TRIED THAT, i have put it in my delegate as you said, with viewdidload, and i dont get any value. got warnning that the delegate is not implement the UIaccelerometerDelegate ..

Comment: thanks but i cant understand, do i have to put all of this in my delegate ? or to open another class ?